# Define the node's property to modify in a variable (Groovy)

Tags: xml, groovy

Is it possible to define the node's property to modify in a variable, and evaluate it to set a new value ?

I have tried something like you can see under... But it doesn't work...

```java
import groovy.xml.*

def myTest = '''
```

```xml
<test:main xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:test="http://www.testexample.com/test">
    <childNode xmi:id="_9_RgZj4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="Boo!" number="1.414"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="_9_RgYz4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="toto" number="42"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="__o_QMT4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="paf" number="12.215"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="_vUeScDy9EeilM5T6mGX42Q" name="pif" number="56.1"/>
</test:main>
```

```java
'''
myTest = new XmlParser(false, true).parseText(myTest)

def var = "number"
def toModify = "myTest.childNode.@" + var
evaluate(toModify) = 42

var = "value"
toModify = "myTest.childNode.@" + var
evaluate(toModify) = 42

println XmlUtil.serialize( myTest )
```

So here, for example, I want to modify *number*. So I set 'number' to *var*, and change the value of "myTest.childNode.@var" that must be interpret by : **myTest.childNode.@number**

Thanks for your attention !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your approach does not match the groovy way, it is not possible to apply a XPATH query string directly to the result of XmlParser.

The beauty of handling XML in groovy is that you get a really powerful set of tools. Applying them to your question yields:

```
def var = 'number'
def nodeName = 'childNode'

// get all numbers on childNode
myTest."$nodeName"."@$var"

// set just a selected number to 48
// the key for the search could also be a variable
myTest."${nodeName}".find { it.@name == "toto"}."@$var" = 48

// set all numbers to 48
myTest."${nodeName}".each { it."@$var" = 48 }

// set all names to something else
var = "name"
myTest."${nodeName}".each { it."@$var" = "something else" }
```

Check out the great documentation of xml processing with groovy at 
http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html.

If you are still interested in the use of a full XPath querystring try this:

```
def setValue(xml, xpathQuery, value) {
    // parse xml
    def data = new XmlParser(false, true).parseText(xml)
    // split query string 
    def fullPath = xpathQuery.split('\\.')
    // prepare query attributes for first recursion and start
    def attribute = fullPath.head(), path = fullPath.tail()
    recursiveSetValue(data, attribute, path, value)
    // for demonstration only
    XmlUtil.serialize(data)
}

def recursiveSetValue(node, attribute, path, value) {
    // in case of a list of nodes branch out
    if(node instanceof NodeList) { 
        node.each {
            recursiveSetValue(it, attribute, path, value)
        }
    // no more elements in path, so this is the element to be set;
    // do it and return
    } else if (path == []) {
        node[attribute] = value
    // continue searching for the matching node on the next level
    } else {
        recursiveSetValue(node[attribute], path.head(), path.tail(), value)
    }
}

def xml = myTest // from your example
// I prefer to leave the @ with number as it directs to the 
// attribute of the XML node instead of a new node
def var = "@number" 
def path = "childNode." + var
def value = 43
setValue (xml, path, value)
```